# Where are the DLL's referenced in my .net C++ Dll/Tlb?

Tags: .net, c++, dll, dll-reference

I created a .net C++ dll, which I then converted to a tlb file for use in a native C++ application. I referenced other external dll's in my dll. Now, I am trying to deploy, and want to copy over the referenced dll's to the deployment computer. Where do they reside in my .net C++ project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior is for the build system to copy any referenced assemblies to your build output directory.  So that you can debug the result.  This copy won't happen when the reference assembly is in the GAC, like is the case with any .NET framework assembly.

In other words, you should find them back in your Release build directory after building.

Comment: thanks. I needed to set the copy local in the build properties of the reference to true, and then it was indeed where you said it would be.